# Can anyone suggest a database schema for my django project?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-orm

I'm currently working on a student management web application built using Django framework. I have confusions while designing the database schema. There are currently 2 different `regulations`, which has 8 `semesters` each and each `semester` have `subject name`, `subject code` and `subject credit`. I wonder how to assign database schema for this tree and assign it to a student. So that each student have only one `regulations`, many `semesters` and related attributes. Can anyone suggest the database schema and Django ORM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create `Regulation` model, then create `semester` model with having `regulation` as a `OneToOne` relation, create `Subject` model with having the `name`, `code` and `credit` and semester as a `OneToOne`, create `Student` model and assign `Regulation` as `OneToOne` relation, i think that will work

Comment: @Mowli Please check the answer. I'm waiting your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand trying to do your model. Let me know if I misunderstand

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Regulation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    semesters = models.ManyToManyField('Semester', related_name='semester_regulation_set')


class Semester(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField('Subject', related_name="subject_semester_set")


class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    credit = models.IntegerField()
    semester = models.ForeignKey('Semester', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    regulation = models.ForeignKey('Regulation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)